# How to restrict special characters in input field in React js by using setValue method of react form hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, onchange

there is one input field inside **useFieldArray **getting data from **API **in editable mode so i want to restrict special characters and numbers in that editable input field. I am using **setValue **function on **OnChange **but it's not working.
I tried to replace the numbers and special characters and fetch the value on console the value is coming correct but in the frontend, value is not updated by **setValue **function.

So, I want to restrict special characters from that input field, and data is coming from an **API **

`

```
const handleWarningName = (name, value, index) => {
    if (name === `warning.${index}.name`) 
    {
      console.log("-----",value,"index" ,index)
      setValue(`warning.${index}.name`, value);
    }
  };
```

`

this is the function of handling the value

`your text`

Comment: Are you using any kind of validators like `zod`? Provide a fuller example, please tell us what do you expect, what are special and non-special characters in your case?

Comment: onChange={(e) => {
                            let name = e.currentTarget.name;
                            let value = e.currentTarget.value;
                            value = value.replace(/[0-9]/g, "");
                            value = value.replace(/\s/g, "");
                            value = value.replace(
                              /[ `!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?~]/g,
                              ""
                            );

Comment: now i have used a function setValue to set this value in input field. but its not updating